# Why directly modifying basic_string.h does not recompile

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, libstdc++

I am not so familiar with std containers. It seems basic_string.h is a template and can be modified to use directly without recompile libstdc++.

Am I correct on this?
Thanks for helps.

Comment: The file is an implementation detail. You are not supposed to use it at all. Follow the standard C++ rules and include `<string>`. If you are working with a C++ compiler, you should have already installed a compiled standard library with it. There is no reason to worry about it. Also, don't modify files belonging to the compiler/standard library.

Comment: I know I am not suppose to modify it. But I want to know whether changing anything in it would effectively change my runtime program. I am using a separate sysroot on my machine so not worrying about breaking things. What is the diff between implementation vs implementation detail?

Comment: The effect on your program will depend on what you change. In general you will need to recompile everything that uses `std::basic_string`, including the standard library, in order to avoid ABI incompatibilities introduced by your changes. Also, libstdc++ specifically uses explicit instantiation into the shared library by default for `std::string` if I remember correctly.

Comment: I changed some macros, there is one named something like fully dynamic string. Should not change any API, but gcc doc says I need to config it with reinstallation option —enable-fully-dynamic-string which I don’t know why I can’t just redefine the macro myself.

Comment: Strangely anything I changed in basic_string.h does not recompile. I could throw garbage there and no compiler errors which makes me wonder how basic_string is used..

Comment: Because it is ABI (but not API) breaking. I would suggest you ask about the actual change you want to make in your question and not as general as it is written right now.

Comment: @GGinside because that breaks OneDefinition Rule within runtime library, breaking binary compatibility of object with its counterpart in compiled code. Effect is undefined, but determined by implementation

Comment: @GGinside *But I want to know whether changing anything in it would effectively change my runtime program.* -- All you will be doing is corrupting your compiler installation.  Then things break down, you have to reinstall the compiler -- do you really want to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to modify the `std` headers of a C++ program under the standard.

Any changing of those files is going to have implementation defined results, where that implementation is your entire compiling tool chain and system library install.

Practically, the most common problem is going to be violating the one definition rule of C++, and the most common symptom of violating the one definition rule is that your changes act as if they didn't happen, because the compiler found two definitions of an inline structure and silently discarded one of them.  The second most common symptom of violating the one definition rule is memory corruption.

In almost no situation does violating the one definition rule end well.

I can type more words that describe why what you are doing is a bad idea, but I think I have written more than enough.

Your question is akin to asking "if I stab myself with a knife randomly, what will actually kill me?"  Working out the exact mechanism distributions of how it kills you is hard, but the real problem is you are stabbing yourself with a knife.